# AzureADConnect: Expression with concatenated string

Tags: entra-id, azureadconnect

Our users are created and maintaned in OnPrem AD and synched to Azure with the AzureADConnect. I am trying to get an expression to work:

We have locations in different countries, so the title of the user in the "title" AD attribute is the title in the local language. We also put the title in english into the "extensionAttribute5". Now I would like to manage that the "title" attribute in AzureAD is the following:

```
If (ExtensionAttribute5 is empty) then (only use "title" ad attribute) else (use "title / extensionAttribute5")
```

It is hard to find exact documentation for the syntax of these expressions, but I read that it shoud be the same as VBA. And as far as I understand it, it should be this:

```
IIF(IsNullOrEmpty([extensionAttribute5]),Trim([title]),[title]&" / "&[extensionAttribute5]
```

But I get "sync-generic-failure" with the message:

> Error in evaluation of expression: IIF(IsNullOrEmpty([extensionAttribute5]),Trim([title]),[title]&" / "&[extensionAttribute5]

Can someone help me with this expression or point me in the direction where I can get help with it?

Comment: If it were me, I'd open a support case with Office 365. It's free. They'll assist with Azure AD Connect issues and may be able to help with your expression.

Comment: That's good to know. In my head all Microsoft support is either complicated or expensive (Gold Partner and stuff...) - but I will check that. Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty awesome that they provide Office 365 support for free, including issues with Azure AD Connect, Exchange Hybrid, etc. Your issue may fall a bit out of scope since it has to deal with "customizing" Azure AD Connect sync rules, but it's worth a shot to contact them.